# Is it possible to dynamically set the name of a decorator in python?

Tags: python, flask, decorator, web-frameworks

So, I was studying the FLASK framework in python and made my very first simple program and by default I've seen people using `app = Flask(__name__)` and just below that line they use the decorator `@app.route("/")`,So  I thought that what would happen if I change the name of the variable to something else? Like in the code below I've changed it to `something = Flask(__name__)`  so now I'm confused that how does it still work when I decorate the function `index()` with `@something.route("/")` ,is the name of the decorator function defined in `FLASK` changing dynamically? and if so how can I make my own decorators like this so that they too change their names dynamically?

```
from flask import Flask 

something = Flask(__name__)

@something.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

Comment: The *decorator is `something`*.  A decorator is just a function (or callable). It is an object like an `int` or a `list`, it can be assigned to any variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decorator is just a syntactic sugar:

```
def decorator(func):
    pass

@decorator
def decorated():
    pass
```

is the same as:

```
def decorator(func):
    pass

def decorated():
    pass

decorated = decorator(decorated)
```

The decorator name is nothing more than a function that accepts one argument. You could even use `print` function as a decorator. Any valid callable will do:

```
@print
def index():
    pass
```

Obviously that makes little sense, because:

```
def index():
    pass

index = print(index)
```

Anyway that's how this could be implemented in flask

```
class Flask:
    def route(self, url):
        def wrapper(func):
            # register route for url
            return func

        return wrapper

something = Flask()

@something.route("/")
def index():
    pass
```

`something.route("/")` is a function call that returns the real decorator which is actually the inner function named wrapper.

So you can even do something like this:

```
something_route_index = something.route("/")

@something_route_index
def index():
    pass
```